# Force UISplitViewController to always show master (only) in landscape (on iPhone 6 Plus)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

In a Universal App I can't find a way to always show (and only) the master controller, even on iPhone 6 Plus in landscape rotation.

What I want to achieve is to see UISplitViewController in action only on the iPad and NOT on the iPhone, don't know if it's possible

delegate methods doesn't help:

```
func splitViewController(svc: UISplitViewController, shouldHideViewController vc: UIViewController, inOrientation orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController: UIViewController, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to override the trait collection of your UISplitViewController to always have a compact size class. To do so you need to insert a container view controller as the parent of your UISplitViewController:

1. Embed your UISplitViewController into a ContainerViewController
2. Add the following code into your container view controller subclass to override the trait collection of your child view controller:

   ```
   class ContainerVC: UIViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
   }

   override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
       performOverrideTraitCollection()
   }

   private func performOverrideTraitCollection() {
       for childVC in self.childViewControllers {
           setOverrideTraitCollection(UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .Compact), forChildViewController: childVC)
       }
   }}
   ```

Great explanation in [Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit (WWDC 2014)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/216/)

Answer (score 0):

Terry's answer works great! Here it is updated to Swift 5 and to work only on iPhone devices, not iPad:

```
class ContainerVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != .pad {
            performOverrideTraitCollection()
        }
    }

    private func performOverrideTraitCollection() {
        for childVC in self.children {
            setOverrideTraitCollection(UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .compact), forChild: childVC)
        }
    }
}
```

**Update For iOS 13**

The code above no longer works on iOS 13. Use the following instead in the ContainerVC class:

```
override func overrideTraitCollection(forChild childViewController: UIViewController) -> UITraitCollection? {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom != .pad {
        return UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .compact)
    } else {
        return super.traitCollection
    }
}
```

Comment: Interested to know more info on the exact situation you had an issue on iOS 13 thanks. Also the first snippet is missing the call to super which is what calls the same method on child view controllers.

Comment: is there way to make it dynamic? such as having initial primary view controller full screen but show detail view controller in the next?