# iOS 13 - UISplitViewController resize bug

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, ios13

I have a weird bug with `UISplitViewController` on iOS 13 (it works fine on iOS 12). I created a simple project to reproduce this bug.

- This app looks as follow, nothing fancy:
  [image]
- I subclassed `UISplitViewController` as follow to allow resizing the `MasterViewController`:

```
final class SplitViewController: UISplitViewController {
    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
        delegate = self
        expandMasterView()
    }

    private func expandMasterView() {
        preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 1
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = max(screenSize.width, screenSize.height)
    }
}

extension SplitViewController: UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
    func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController,
                             collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController,
                             onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Whenever I load the `SplitViewController`, I want to expand the `MasterViewController` to the full `UIScreen` width. If I run this project, I get this result:

[image]

- Now if I change the line:

```
maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = max(screenSize.width, screenSize.height)
```

to

```
maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = max(screenSize.width - 1, screenSize.height - 1)
```

I obtain what I want:

[image]

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57161013/8272698

Comment: @JulianSilvestri Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: @DrS did you find the solution? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @AndreLiberty Unfortunately not. I ended up with the following code: 
```let gap = 1.0 / self.traitCollection.displayScale

maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = max(screenSize.width - gap, screenSize.height - gap)
```. I have also filled a bug on feedbackassistant.apple.com

Comment: @DrS ok, thank you for the reply!